# Few doubts related Windows push Notification service in WP Universal application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am a Windows Phone application developer. In my application I implemented push notification services using WNS .
I have few doubts/questions regarding this. Please clarify

1. How can we disable push notification for a specific application ? Can we prevent it from application side ? Or handle it from server side?
2. If I un install my application and the server is still sending you the push notifications. Will it receive in to phone?
3. Is that necessary to ask user permission before registering push notification channel ?
4. Can we get notifications history of notifications received on my phone and not attended? Is there any api for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general WNS information see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx

For your questions:

1.How can we disable push notification for a specific application ? Can we prevent it from application side ? Or handle it from server side?

From the application you can unregister your channelUri:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhub.unregisterallasync(v=azure.10).aspx

2.If I un install my application and the server is still sending you the push notifications. Will it receive in to phone?

Not it should not receive any more push notifications

3.Is that necessary to ask user permission before registering push notification channel ?

Yes

4.Can we get notifications history of notifications received on my phone and not attended? Is there any api for that ?

You can use the classes in Windows.UI.NOtifications namespace to manage your applciations notifications on the client:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.aspx

Specifically Toast Notification History:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationhistory.aspx

Comment: sorry for the late question, Toast Notification History class you have mentioned have only method for clear and remove. How we will get the toast notifications data list that have received on the device so far ?