# How to handle WNS push notifications in Windows Phone 8.1 -silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I implemented **WNS push notification** in my Windows Phone application. And the application are getting the toast notifications successfully.[Sometimes with a delay].

Now toast notification functionality will work only when the user **tap** it when the application is not open. In any case the user swipe out the notifications form the action center,so the user could not see the missed notifications.

> Is there any way or api to get/store those entire toast notification
>   list in Windows phone ?

I know [ToastNotificationHistory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.aspx)  class, But where I could see only clear or remove notifications.Please provide me clarification on it is possible or not ?

Also when the device is on **low power state**, no toast notifications are coming on the device. So the user misses that too. How to handle this case too ?

Please provide me a detailed clarifications on my work around.

related SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144953/few-doubts-related-windows-push-notification-service-in-wp-universal-application)

Thanking you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Hi asitis, I would like you to know that `ToastNotificationFactory's
  Clear and Remove` methods only apply to those notifications that are
  generated by the app itself(local notifications). These methods can not do
  what they are saying to those notifications that are coming from WNS
  service.
- Also You don't have much control over the WNS notifications when
  application is closed. They are all handled by user. Like if they
  have deleted them or read then they are not available anymore.
- May your functionality will be fulfilled by your own server that does
  this saving/retrieving notification things. over an endpoint to your 
  client app. Then you may use Background agents to fetch these
  notifications without the user interaction and send the internal
  notification to the user from background agent itself.
- But background agents are not the good things because they eat the
  battery and user can intentionally disable them for all apps. so your
  implementation will not be of any use.

So IMO please review your requirement and try to figure out what exactly you need. Also read guidelines of pushnotifications usage I think this => [Push Notification Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761462.aspx) will definitely help.

**Notification Disabling** :- for this don't use any client side logic/code because in this case you have to re-publish the client(app) every time your logic changes. So put this logic from where(server) you are sending the notifications. like :- filtering if users..
you can change this filter logic according to your needs in future.

Hope it help you :)

Comment: It really helps . Thank you. So for better experience we need to use   a separate api for handling notifications. Right ? and another one question . How to disable notification ?

Comment: for the first question - yes. second one i've edited the answer